# PHP - Select 5 random characters in a string?

Tags: php

How can I randomly select 5 characters from a given string? They can repeat.

Say my string is this:

```
static $chars = "123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
```

I just want 5 random characters out of that variable. Thanks to anyone who can help me out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php

Comment: It seems [`Random::stringFromAlphabet($chars, $length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) is exactly what you want. But it also comes with pre-defined alphabets that seem to do what you wanted to achieve, e.g. `Random::alphanumericHumanString($length)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function gen_code() {

    $charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

    return substr(str_shuffle($charset), 0, 5);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient in both memory and processing. This causes the entire string to be reordered randomly into a new string, which, depending on the length of the string, can incur significant cost.  You only need 5 random characters, yet the shuffling has to generate 62 (technically 61) in the example above.
Additionally, the same character can't be chosen twice, which isn't something the question stipulates.

Answer (score 2):

Just create 5 random indices and grab the characters from the string:

```
$chars = "123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
$length = strlen($chars) - 1;
$randchars = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $position = mt_rand(0, $length);
    $randchars .= $chars[$position];
}
echo $randchars;
```

If you simply want to get a 5 character long random string then there are better ways of doing it. Getting random data from the operating system, and then encoding it, would be the ideal way:

```
function random_string($length) {
    $raw   = (int) ($length * 3 / 4 + 1);
    $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv($raw, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $rand  = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($bytes));
    return substr($rand, 0, $length);
}
echo random_string(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working Please Try it,

```
<?php
    $length = 5;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
    echo $randomString;
?>
```

Comment: There are already two answers that are identical to this one. Further more, shuffling the string does not allow for repeating characters.

Comment: I have checked and than post, Thanks for +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  static $chars = "123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
  $chars=str_shuffle($chars);
  $finalString=substr($chars, 0,5);
```

Comment: Down voter why down vote me?? Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass your `$chars` into this function and it will return you 5 random characters.

```
// to generate random string

function rand_str($length = 5, $chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    // Length of character list
    $chars_length = (strlen($chars) - 1);
    // Start our string
    $string = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
    // Generate random string
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i = strlen($string))
    {
        // Grab a random character from our list
        $r = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
       // Make sure the same two characters don't appear next to each other
       if ($r != $string{$i - 1}) $string .=  $r;
    }
    // Return the string
    return $string;
}

// function ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = explode(',' , '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z,B,C,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,X,Y,Z');
$string ='';
for($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
    $string .= $var[rand(0, count($var)-1)];
}


echo $string;
```

Edit* Had an off by one error, "count($var)" should be "count($var)-1"

Comment: PHP needs to explode that string on every single request. It is unnecessary and easily avoided. Since you are already using a `for` loop you can just as well work with a string, which is must faster and uses less memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
//define a function    
function generateRandomString($length = 5){
    $chars = "123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
}

//usage
echo generateRandomString(5); //random string legth: 5
echo generateRandomString(6); //random string legth: 6
echo generateRandomString(7); //random string legth: 7
```