# Codeigniter hash value not changing in loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash

I am attempting to use the codeigniter security class to generate a unique long code which I can use to update an online db securely:

```
http://mydomain.com/myproject/index.php/my_controller/index/***3d51693c8c4***..
```

I noticed that when I create a hash for individual records in a loop using:

```
$hash= $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
```

the same hash keeps getting generated. I need a unique hash/security code to be generated for each record in my loop. I don't see anything in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/security.html discussing how to do this.

What is the best way to do this in CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a unique code that you want to generate, why not build one yourself with built-in php function?

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
   $hash = uniqid(md5(time()), true);
   var_dump($hash);
}

?>
```

Sample output: http://pastebin.com/eSWaLhUt

As you can see, it's unique, regardless of how fast you iterate through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with this.

Answer (score 1):

The `uniqid` method will supply a unique security code (be sure to use the `more_entropy` argument however this isn't particulary secure so depending on what you're using it for consider using `mt_rand`.

[uniqid docs](http://php.net/uniqid)

[mt_rand docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the OS to generate unique values. This solution is a *nix only solution, but one of my favs

```
/** 
 * A Linux-dependent password generator.  This seems to be about 1000x better than
 * typical PHP-based password generation, and from what I hear, /dev/urandom should
 * be secure enough for temporary passwords.
 *
 * Lifted from:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php
 */
static public function generatePassword($iLength=0)
{   
    $rFp = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
    if(!$rFp)
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't access /dev/urandom to get random data.");

    // 1024 bytes should be enough
    $sRandom = fread($rFp, 1024);
    fclose($rFp);

    return substr(trim(base64_encode(md5($sRandom, true)), '='), $iLength * -1);
}
```

Comment: Good Info. In my case I develop with windows