# Auto generating password generating up to n values and display into new line PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code from auto generating passwords and i want to produce up to 40 times of random passwords and displaying it into a new line.

```
$num = 0;
while($num != 40){
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
print_r ($pass);
echo implode("<br>",$pass);
$num++;
}
```

the code separates the array per strings into new line. I need to display a strings with 8 characters up to 40 times per line.

Comment: `rand` is not suitable to generate secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo implode("<br>",$pass);`, you're looking for `echo implode($pass) . "<br />";`

```
$num = 0;
while($num != 40){
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
    print_r ($pass);
    echo implode($pass) . "<br />";
    $num++;
}
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/V3q8h)**.

Note that `rand()` is **[not a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101969/2341603)**, and should not be used for password generation. For such tasks, I would recommend checking out some of **[these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956)**. Keep in mind that length is far more important than complexity with regards to brute-forcing, so you may also wish to up your lengths from `8`.

Comment: I understand you only touched the line that produces an output, but a tiny warning that `rand` is a poor choice to generate any kind of passwords would be helpful as well (upvoted anyway) PS: kia ora :-)

Comment: I've added a quick note on `rand()`'s weaknesses, and linked to the question that this code appears to be based off of. There's plenty of answers there on more secure password generations -- though password complexity definitely comes second to password length. Kia ora! :)