# Flaw in laravel hash

Tags: laravel, hash, bcrypt

we are using `Laravel Framework 5.7.15 with PHP version: 7.2.14-1`
and  we use below code to generate temporary password then hash it in the database.
In around 80 times all passwords hash matched the string however there were around 3 not matched strings , I searched for a cause and nothing appeared...

```
$input['tmp_password'] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, 4); // Random four digits
$input['password'] = Hash::make($input['tmp_password']);
```

Comment: That is a really bad way to generate a random password. Why not do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php. Even the PHP help page for `str_shuffle` warns you not to use this function for things that need to be secure.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? You posted two lines of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "not matched"? Are you saying `Hash::check` if failing on the generated hashes? That's extraordinarily unlikely.

Comment: We are using this method because we want a simple random password , and yes hash check and this is why this is so weird

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments there are better ways to generate random passwords other than using str_shuffle. Using this method the passwords generated will always contain the same given chars just in a different order, making it easy to guess.

One example of a better way is using the helper method `random` from [Str class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-random)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$password = Hash::make(Str::random(40)); // 40 being the number of chars generated
```

Comment: The problem is with hash check not in generating the password

Comment: How are you using the hash check? can you update your question with a small sample?

Comment: Hash::check($input['password'], $user->password)){

Answer (score 1):

In ten thousand iterations of your code, I was unable to cause a single hash to fail.

```
$input = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $input['tmp_password'] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, 4);
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['tmp_password']);

    if(!Hash::check($input['tmp_password'], $input['password'])) {
        print "OH SHIT\n";
    }
}
```

Something else is going wrong, in code you haven't shown. As you indicate in the comments, you're doing some other stuff with `$user` somewhere that's not in your code sample at all.

Comment: actually it was UI issue if user double clicks on create button two passwords are created and the only the second is saved

Comment: That would indeed be "Something else is going wrong, in code you haven't shown".