# convert to numbers with php

Tags: php, numbers, int

I made a random code with md5, but how to make the code contains only numbers

```
  $this->db->select('RIGHT(service.tracking_number,4) as kode', FALSE);
  $this->db->order_by('id_service','DESC');    
  $this->db->limit(1);    
    $query = $this->db->get('service');         
      if($query->num_rows() <> 0){         
       $data = $query->row();      
       $kode = intval($data->kode) + 1;    
      }else {           
       $kode = 1;    
      }
  $kodemax = str_pad($kode, 1, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
  $kodejadi = "RJC".md5($kodemax);    
  $hasil = substr($kodejadi, 0,-15);
  return $hasil;  

  output RJC1679091c5a880faf6
```

how to make these output numbers?

Comment: Basically you want a random numeric output?

Comment: yes sir, help :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a random password in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101956/generating-a-random-password-in-php)

Comment: Why can't you use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php instead of MD5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random number you can use this snippet:

```
$count = 10;
$key = '';
$chars = '0123456789';
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
  $key = $key.$chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
}

echo $key;
```